# Atonement and the Death Penalty

Tags: avodah-zarah, capital-punishment, kaparah-atonement

"Ordinary murderers are allowed to achieve atonement for their souls in their execution. Only especially vile murderers - such as a false witness whose lies are discovered after the person who was framed has been executed, or a man who sacrifices both his son and his daughter to the pagan god Molokh - are denied execution because they are regarded as beyond redemption through capital punishment."

Which Jewish sources support this statement?

The quote from above is an excerpt from an article written by Steven Plaut(2004) for the Jewish press: http://archive.frontpagemag.com/readArticle.aspx?ARTID=13290

Comment: [Sanhedrin 64b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=64b&format=pdf) [Makkot 5b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=5b&format=pdf) [Sanhedrin 6:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.6.2)

Comment: Hello TOJew, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your first question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: @DoubleAA, it seems like you have an answer. Why not post it as such?